# Is there a way to specify a suggested tag name inside a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The same way it's possible to list possible volume mount points with the VOLUME statement, it would seem sensible to specify a default image name with a "TAG" statement or similar.

Is this possible in Docker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible; the name of the resulting image can only be specified during `docker build`, or afterwards, using `docker tag` (and `docker commit`).

There was a proposal for this, but it's not accepted; see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5603 for the discussion on this.